# Путь к файлу/ресурсу в библиотеке

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть своя библиотека классов, в которой есть файл (например, xsd). Как получить доступ к этому файлу из консольного и ASP MVC проекта?

Comment: Получить файл в каком виде? Добавьте в библиотеку публичный метод `GetXsd()` и вызывайте его из клиента этой библиотеки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если используете эту библиотек в нескольких проектах, то оформите библиотеку как Nuget пакет и при инсталляции в ваш проект, заранее определенные файлы, в папке "content", будут копироваться в проект.
Дальше работайте как с обычными файлами из проекта.

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#From_a_convention_based_working_directory

Раздел "The folder conventions are as follows:"

Answer (score 0):

В ASP.NET MVC файлы из библиотеки, если их пометить **копировать**, то они попадают в папку **bin**